# Disjunctive Normal Form (DNF) of a boolean combination

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic

Upon revisiting  chapter 1 of  Robert S. Wolf's "A tour though mathematical logic" I sumbled upon  the following  Proposition on page 13 :

> > Suppose that $P$ is a Boolean combination of statements $Q_1,Q_2, \ldots , Q_n$. Then there is a statement that is propositionally equivalent to $P$  and is in disjunctive normal form with respect to $Q_1,Q_2, \ldots, Q_n$, meaning a disjunction of conjunctions  of the $Q_i$'s and their negations

This is accompanied by the following "proof":

> > Essentially, the disjunctive normal form of a statement comes directly from its truth table. Each row 
> >     of the truth table with output T indicates one of the conjunctions whose 
> >     disjunction must be taken.

I am a weary of the informality of the  proof , and I went searching for a more  formal proof.

Most of the potential proofs that I found seem to rely on a through discussion of  First order  language.  Which is discussed   later on in the chapter.

So is a more formal proof possible without definition and a discussion  of first order logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0122384520) (2nd - 2001), page 47 :

> **Theorem 15B** : Let G be an $n$-place Boolean function, $n \ge 1$. We can find a wff $\alpha$ such that $G = B^n_{\alpha}$, i.e., such that $\alpha$ realizes the function G

where :

> Suppose that $\alpha$ is a wff whose sentence symbols are at most $A_1,..., A_n$. We define an $n$-place Boolean function $B^n_{\alpha}$, the Boolean function *realized by* $\alpha$, by :
>
> > $B^n_{\alpha}(X_1,..., Х_n)$ = the truth value given to $\alpha$ when $A_1, ..., A_n$ are given the values $X_1, ..., X_n$.

Then [page 49] :

> **Corollary 15C** : For any wff $\varphi$, we can find a tautologically equivalent wff $\alpha$ in *disjunctive normal form*.